# How to make jagged diagonal lines in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I've found multiple questions about how to make jagged diagonal lines in HTML Canvas smoother, but I am having the **opposite** problem. That is, I'd like to be able to set a 'jaggedness' parameter and have rendered diagonal lines have a corresponding detail level.

I am using Canvas to make a game with a pixel art aesthetic, and I am scaling all of my art assets and fonts by 4, so that each 4x4 pixel area on the screen corresponds to a single pixel visually. This has worked pretty well so far, but now I'd like to draw some UI using native canvas functions, and I want the results to be visually consistent with my approach so far. So far I've tried this, but lineWidth only affects the thickness of the line and not the aliasing level.

```
ctx.lineWidth=4;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.stroke();
```

One potential solution is to render a diagonal series of boxes that are offset by 4 pixels in both directions, but I hope there is something more efficient out there.

Comment: You could use a [turtle](https://rawgit.com/wrschneider99/js-turtle/master/turtle.html)

Comment: What does this have to do with my problem?

Comment: Not entirely a dupe but must contain an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625903/faster-bresenham-line-for-html-canvas