# Draw a Filled Polygon using Scanline Loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, html5-canvas, polygon

I'm trying to draw a filled polygon using individual pixels in a scanline loop (so no `lineTo` or `fill` Canvas methods).

I was able to achieve a triangle in this method (example below), but I'm not sure where to begin with a more complex polygon (such as a star shape ★). Can anyone give any advice on how to approach this or existing shape algorithm examples for Javascript & Canvas?

I have researched Bresenham’s Algorithm but was unsuccessful implementing it for polygons because of my limited understanding of it. Please let me know if anything I've explained is unclear.

Thank you!

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var widthRange = document.querySelector('#widthRange')
var heightRange = document.querySelector('#heightRange')
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

var DrawPixel = function (x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

var x = 100;
var y = 100;
var width = widthRange.value;
var height = heightRange.value;

const draw = () =>
{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
  wHRatio = width/height;
  for (var j=0; j<height; j++)
  {
    w = width-j*wHRatio;
    for (var i=0; i<w; i++)
    {
      DrawPixel(Math.floor(i+(j*(wHRatio/2))),height-j);
    }
  }
}

draw();

widthRange.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  width = e.currentTarget.value;
  draw();
})

heightRange.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  height = e.currentTarget.value;
  draw();
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}

.slidecontainer
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <label for="widthRange">Width</label>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="300" value="100" class="slider" id="widthRange">
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <label for="heightRange">Height</label>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="150" value="100" class="slider" id="heightRange">
</div>
<canvas width=300 height=150 id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scanline for non self intersecting polygons.

Draw any concave or convex polygon with 3 or more sides using scanline method.

- Is the easiest, also slowest.
- Polygon is a set of lines with start and end points.
- Polygon lines can be unordered
- Polygon must be closed
- None of polygon lines can cross any of the other polygon lines.

#### Steps

```
Find bounding box of lines. top, left, right, bottom.
Set x, y to  top left of bounding box.
while y is less than bottom.
    Find all lines that will cross the line from left, y to right, y
    Sort lines in distance from x to point where above line crossed
    while there are sorted lines
        shift two lines from sorted lines and scan the pixels between
    add 1 to y
```

#### An implementation.

Function `scanlinePoly(lines, col)` draw the pixels. `lines` is create with `createLines` which is an array of lines with helper functions to add lines, find lines, sort lines, and get bounds.

Helper functions

- `createStar(x, y, r1, r2, points)` will create a `lines` array for a star, `x`, `y` center of star, `r1` radius, `r2` second radius, `points` number of points
- `P2(x, y)` returns 2D point
- `L2(p1, p2)` returns  2D line that includes the slope of the line. `p1`, `p2` are points as created by `P2`
- `atLineLevelY(y)` returns true if line crosses scan line at `y`

```js
const scanlinePoly = (lines, col) => {
    const b = lines.getBounds();
    var x, y, xx;
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    b.left = Math.floor(b.left);
    b.top = Math.floor(b.top);
    for (y = b.top; y <= b.bottom; y ++) {
        // update 
        // old line was const ly = lines.getLinesAtY(y).sortLeftToRightAtY(y);
        // changed to
        const ly = lines.getLinesAtY(y + 0.5).sortLeftToRightAtY(y + 0.5);
        x = b.left - 1; 
        while(x <= b.right) {
            const nx1 = ly.nextLineFromX(x);
            if (nx1 !== undefined) {
                const nx2 = ly.nextLineFromX(nx1);
                if (nx2 !== undefined) {
                    const xS = Math.floor(nx1); 
                    const xE = Math.floor(nx2); 
                    for (xx = xS; xx < xE; xx++) {
                        ctx.fillRect(xx, y, 1, 1);
                    }
                    x = nx2;
                } else { break }
            } else { break }
        }
    }
}

function createLines(linesArray = []) {
     return   Object.assign(linesArray, {
        addLine(l) { this.push(l) },
        getLinesAtY(y) { return createLines(this.filter(l => atLineLevelY(y, l))) },
        sortLeftToRightAtY(y) {
            for (const l of this) { l.dist = l.p1.x + l.slope * (y - l.p1.y) }
            this.sort((a,b) => a.dist - b.dist);
            return this;
        },
        nextLineFromX(x) { // only when sorted
            const line = this.find(l => l.dist > x);
            return line ? line.dist : undefined;
        },
        getBounds() {
            var top = Infinity, left = Infinity;
            var right = -Infinity,  bottom = -Infinity;
            for (const l of this) {
                top = Math.min(top, l.p1.y, l.p2.y);
                left = Math.min(left, l.p1.x, l.p2.x);
                right = Math.max(right, l.p1.x, l.p2.x);
                bottom = Math.max(bottom, l.p1.y, l.p2.y);
            }
            return {top, left, right, bottom};
        },
    });
}

const createStar = (x, y, r1, r2, points) => {
    var i = 0, pFirst, p1, p2;
    const lines = createLines()
    while (i < points * 2) {
        const r = i % 2 ? r1 : r2;
        const ang = (i / (points * 2)) * Math.PI * 2;
        p2 = P2(Math.cos(ang) * r + x, Math.sin(ang) * r + y);
        if (pFirst === undefined) { pFirst = p2 };
        if (p1 !== undefined) { lines.addLine(L2(p1, p2)) }
        p1 = p2;
        i++;
    }
    lines.addLine(L2(p2, pFirst));    
    return lines;
}
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const P2 = (x = 0,y = 0) => ({x, y});
const L2 = (p1 = P2(), p2 = P2()) => ({p1, p2, slope: (p2.x - p1.x) / (p2.y - p1.y)});
const atLineLevelY = (y, l) => l.p1.y < l.p2.y && (y >= l.p1.y && y <= l.p2.y) || (y >= l.p2.y && y <= l.p1.y);

canvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
    const star = createStar(
        100, 90, 
        Math.random() * 80 + 10,
        Math.random() * 80 + 10,
        Math.random() * 20 + 2 | 0
    );
    scanlinePoly(star, "#F00")


})


const star = createStar(100, 90, 90, 40, 10);
scanlinePoly(star, "#F00")
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="180"></canvas>Click for rand star
```

**Note** that inner loop

```
for (xx = xS; xx < xE; xx++) {
    ctx.fillRect(xx, y, 1, 1);
}
```

Can be replaced with `ctx.fillRect(xS, y, xE - xS, 1)` to greatly improve performance.

### UPDATE

Looking at my answer again to see if it could be improved I noticed a problem that resulted in lines incorrectly rendered.

To fix the the first line inside the outer loop of function `scanlinePoly`
needs to be changed from.

```
const ly = lines.getLinesAtY(y).sortLeftToRightAtY(y);
```

To

```
const ly = lines.getLinesAtY(y + 0.5).sortLeftToRightAtY(y + 0.5);
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! :D I am learning so much from you. Thank you!!! By the way, how does the fillRect change improve performance?

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain Because the GPU can fill a line of pixels in near the same time as it can fill one pixel, and much faster than using a JS loop to draw pixels one at a time

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain Just to inform you that there was a problem in the example code. I have updated the answer (Details at bottom) to fix the problem.

Comment: I've just been trying different shapes and this works like a charm. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. I am trying to draw a rectangle, but having an issue:
`const rectangle = createLines();
rectangle.addLine(L2(P2(0, 0),P2(200,0)));
rectangle.addLine(L2(P2(200, 0),P2(200,200)));
rectangle.addLine(L2(P2(200, 200),P2(0,200)));
rectangle.addLine(L2(P2(0, 200),P2(0,0)));
scanlinePoly(rectangle, "#F00");`

It seems like the last line's P2's `x` & `y` values have to be greater than the first line's `x` & `y` values in the case of 0.

Can you tell me what is going wrong please? Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain My bad, sorry :(. When a vertical line is the same value of the bounding box left it can not be seen by `lines.nextLineFromX` as the line must be right of x (eg x < ) To prevent an infinite loop the fix is in function `scanlinePoly` second line in outer loop. was `x = b.left;` change to `x = b.left - 1;`. I will update answer

Comment: Don't be sorry! You created an INCREDIBLE function for scanline drawing! Thank you for the quick reply & fix!

Comment: I don't know if you saw my previous comment where I was having troubles, but it is all fixed now. I also wanted to share the result of your function with a complex polygon (working great!):
https://codepen.io/blastframe/pen/XWjYpwE

Comment: Is there an easy way to add a stroke to this polygon? In `scanlinePoly`'s draw call, I've tried `if (xx == xS) || (xx == xE-1) || (y2==b.bottom-1) || (y2==b.top) { [draw pixel with stroke color] }`, but it doesn't account for horizontal lines in between the top & bottom of the polygon.

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain It can be done but it becomes very complex using this algorithm. However you can draw the line segments  using Bresenham line algorithm. The function can be found  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50625904/3877726 I am not sure how well it fit the polygon edges (You may get some holes between ploy and line). To fix that requires a whole new ploy function (one that uses the same error accumulation method as the line) But its complex and  only works with convex polys thus will need to include algorithm to divide convex polys into concave.

Comment: Thank you for the info!