# Rotating an Image without CanvasRenderingContext2D.rotate()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, trigonometry

I would like to rotate an image drawn to Canvas with Javascript, but without using the Context's `rotate` method (or any JS library). The reason is because this is demonstrating an issue I am having in another language where I do not have access to these.

I have created a first draft (below), but I have two issues with my implementation: the pixel-by-pixel rotation of the copied bitmap is extremely slow and it is leaving gaps between the pixels.

Is there a faster method for putting the bitmap data at an angle that would not leave the gaps? Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

```js
const c1 = document.getElementById("c1");
const c2 = document.getElementById("c2");
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');

const removeAllChildNodes = (parent) =>
{
    while (parent.firstChild) {
        parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
    }
}

const rotatedBoundingBox = (width,height,rotation) =>
{
  let rot_w = Math.abs(width * Math.cos(rotation)) + Math.abs(height * Math.sin(rotation));
  let rot_h = Math.abs(width * Math.sin(rotation)) + Math.abs(height * Math.cos(rotation));
  return {width:rot_w,height:rot_h};
}

const render = (rotation) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
  let txt = "Hello World";
  ctx.font = '20px sans-serif';
  let metrics = ctx.measureText(txt);
  canvas.width = metrics.width;
  canvas.height = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent + metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#636674";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = '20px sans-serif';
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffaefa";
  ctx.fillText(txt, canvas.width/2, canvas.height);

  const { width, height } = rotatedBoundingBox(canvas.width,canvas.height,rotation);
  canvas2.width = width;
  canvas2.height = height;

  cos = Math.cos(-rotation);
  sin = Math.sin(-rotation);
  cx = canvas.width/2;
  cy = canvas.height/2;

  for (x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++)
  {
    for (y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++)
    {
      var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
      var pix = imgd.data;
      var red = pix[0];
      var green = pix[1];
      var blue = pix[2];
      var alpha = pix[3];
      nx = ((cos * (x-cx)) + (sin * (y - cy))+canvas2.width/2);
      ny = ((cos * (y-cy)) - (sin * (x - cx))+canvas2.height/2);
      ctx2.putImageData(imgd, nx, ny);
    }
  }

  removeAllChildNodes(c1);
  removeAllChildNodes(c2);
  c1.appendChild(canvas);
  c2.appendChild(canvas2);
}

slider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  document.getElementById('currentDegree').innerHTML = e.target.value;
  const rad = parseInt(e.target.value) * Math.PI / 180;
  render(rad);
})

document.getElementById('currentDegree').innerHTML = slider.value;
render(parseInt(slider.value) * Math.PI / 180);
```

```css
canvas
{
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

main
{
  display: flex;
}

.contain
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="66"/>
  <span>rotation: <span id="currentDegree">0</span>&#176;</span>
</div>
<main>
<div id="c1" class="contain">
</div>
<div id="c2" class="contain">
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: have your tried `transform` css?

Comment: @Francisco Thank you for the reply. As mentioned in the post, this is not for something that will end up in HTML, so I will not be able to use CSS. I believe the solution will be with a more efficient draw loop.

Comment: Every time you call getImageData, the bitmap goes from the GPU to the CPU then to the GPU again. It is extremely slow, so do it as little as possible. Luckily, you can get more than one pixel. So get the full image's imagedata, loop through this single imagedata and compose only one new ImageData. Once this new ImageData is complete, put it a single time on your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scanline 2D image render.

To remove holes in the render scan each pixel you are rendering to and calculate where on that image that pixel is from.

There is a slight cost in that you end up scanning pixels that have no content however that can be resolved if you use a [scanline polygon render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65583346/3877726)

### Simple example

The example below creates an image, gets the pixels of the image and also creates a buffer to hold rendered pixels.

Rather than read and write pixels per channel, it creates a `Uint32Array` view of the buffers so all 4 pixel channels can be read and written in one operation.

Because the image is uniform the scan lines can be optimized such that the full transform need only be calculated once per row.

The scanline function takes 6 arguments. `ox`, `oy` The rotation origin, `ang` the rotation in radians, `scale` the scale to render the image, `r32` Uint32Array view of image Data contains the image to draw. `w32` Uint32Array view of image data to hold the resulting render.

It is reasonably performant, with the example rendering about 160,000 pixels per update.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const W = ctx.canvas.width, H = ctx.canvas.height;
createTestImage();
const pxWrite = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
const w32 = new Uint32Array(pxWrite.data.buffer); /* not needed for 8 bit ver */
const pxRead = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
const r32 = new Uint32Array(pxRead.data.buffer);  /* not needed for 8 bit ver */

function rotate() {
    const ang = angSlider.value * (Math.PI / 180);
    const scale = scaleSlider.value / 100;

    /* For 8bit replace the following line with the commented line below it */
    scanLine(W / 2, H / 2, ang, scale, r32, w32);
    // scanLine8Bit(W / 2, H / 2, ang, scale, pxRead.data, pxWrite.data);

    ctx.putImageData(pxWrite,0,0);
}
function scanLine(ox, oy, ang, scale, r32, w32) {
    const xAx = Math.cos(ang) / scale;
    const xAy = Math.sin(ang) / scale;
    w32.fill(0);
    var rx, ry, idxW, x = 0, y = 0;
    while (y < H) {
        const xx = x - ox, yy = y - oy;
        rx = xx * xAx - yy * xAy + ox; // Get image coords for row start
        ry = xx * xAy + yy * xAx + oy;
        idxW = y * W + x;
        while (x < W) {
            if (rx >= 0 && rx < W && ry >= 0 && ry < H) {
                w32[idxW] = r32[(ry | 0) * W + (rx | 0)]; 
            }
            idxW ++;
            rx += xAx;
            ry += xAy;
            x++;
        }
        y ++;
        x = 0;
    }
}


function scanLine8Bit(ox, oy, ang, scale, r8, w8) {
    var rx, ry, idxW, idxR, x = 0, y = 0;
    const xAx = Math.cos(ang) / scale;
    const xAy = Math.sin(ang) / scale;
    w8.fill(0);  // clears the buffer
    while (y < H) {
        const xx = x - ox, yy = y - oy;
        rx = xx * xAx - yy * xAy + ox; // Get image coords for row start
        ry = xx * xAy + yy * xAx + oy;
        idxW = (y * W + x) * 4;
        while (x < W) {
            if (rx >= 0 && rx < W && ry >= 0 && ry < H) {
                idxR = ((ry | 0) * W + (rx | 0)) * 4;
                w8[idxW++] = r8[idxR++]; // red 
                w8[idxW++] = r8[idxR++]; // green
                w8[idxW++] = r8[idxR++]; // blue
                w8[idxW++] = r8[idxR++]; // alpha
            } else {
                idxW += 4;
            }
            rx += xAx;
            ry += xAy;
            x++;
        }
        y ++;
        x = 0;
    }
}


angSlider.addEventListener("input", rotate);
scaleSlider.addEventListener("input", rotate);
rotate();
function createTestImage() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, W - 40, H - 40);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, W - 80, H - 80);
    ctx.font = "120px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.lineWidth = 8;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.strokeText("Scanline!", W / 2, H / 2);
    ctx.fillText("Scanline!", W / 2, H / 2);
}
```

```css
.inputCont {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
label { background: #FFF9 }
#scaleSlider { width: 400px }
#angSlider { width: 400px }
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #8C8;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101; 
  padding-top: 0px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  margin-top: -5px; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="320"></canvas>
<div class="inputCont">
  <label for="angSlider">Angle</label>
  <input id="angSlider" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="5" /><br>
  <label for="scaleSlider">Scale</label>
  <input id="scaleSlider" type="range" min="10" max="500" value="100" />
  
</div>
```

**Note** that in this example it is expected that the image and render result resolutions are the same size. This can easily be changed.

**Note** It uses a simple "nearest pixel" to get image pixels, so there will be artifacts due to aliasing. However it is very easy to add high quality anti aliasing (via sub pixel sampling) at the cost of performance.

### Update

I have updated the example code re the comment *"Would anything major need to change if I have to do this with arrays of r,g,b,a values?"*

I have added comments instructing what to change and a second function `scanLine8Bit` that will render the content using arrays of bytes (8Bit) for the color channels RGBA. 4 bytes for each pixel.

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you very much! As this will eventually end up in Python, can you please explain what is happening with the read & write data buffers & Uint32Arrays (which I believe is bytearray in Python?)? From what I can tell by the code and your description, this draws to canvas, then (in the `scanline` function) it rotates the rows from `r32` and stores them in `w32`. How is `pxWrite`'s imageData being updated by `w32` after the `scanline` function? Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain `pxWrite.data` (`w8` for comment) and `w32` both point to the same RAM buffer. `w32` indexes 32Bit words, and `w8` indexes 8bit bytes. Setting  `w32[0] = 0xFF00FF00` sets the same RAM as `w8` indexes 0 - 3`  `[0,255,0,255]` Thus setting `w32` updates `pxWrite` at same time and is ~4 times quicker. Reverse is true, setting `d8[0]=255` RED will also set the first 8 bits of `w32[0]` and `w8[3] = 255` ALPHA sets the last 8 bits of `w32[0]`. Channel order for `w32` is `AABBGGRR` thus orange is `0xFF0088FF` (red ch right most) equivalent to CSS color `#FF8800FF` (red ch left most)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Please forgive my limited programming knowledge, but I'm still pretty confused: how is it pointing to the same RAM buffer if you're creating a new instance with `new Uint32Array(pxWrite.data.buffer);`?

Also, let's assume I can't figure out how to convert the image data to a 32 Bit Array in Python. Would anything major need to change if I have to do this with arrays of r,g,b,a values? Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain I have updated answer (see bottom) and code with example using byte indexing (8Bit )  The call  `new Uint32Array(pxWrite.data.buffer);` create a new VIEW of the buffer referenced by `pxWrite.data.buffer` It does not create a new array. They share the same buffer that contains the pixel data. (Same location in RAM) The only difference is the word size 32 or 8 bits, and indexing every 4  or 1 byte  Eg `w32[4]` is the 5th pixel, the same pixel that is at  `w8[16]`, `w8[17]`,  `w8[18]`,  `w8[19]` R,G,B,A

Comment: Hi Blindman67, I have got something working with your code for rotating & row looping but my implementation still has aliasing holes. https://imgur.com/a/DtKYqel Rather than using the buffers that are available in JS & Canvas, I'm writing pixel data directly to my application's API's Bitmap class. I apologize as the code is Python, but could you have a look and see if anything jumps out as the cause? https://pastebin.com/4yf5XxJZ Your scanline version did not have the aliasing issue. Thank you!!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain You have the coordinates and I think the bitmaps, the wrong way around. x, y are the write positions (the pixels you are setting / rendering) and rx, ry are the read positions ( the pixels you are getting pixels from)

Comment: Yes!!!! That fixed the aliasing holes issue. Now the loop does not render the entire destination image though. https://imgur.com/hiT4fzT The reason I'd removed the line `if (rx >= 0 and rx < w and ry >= 0 and ry < h):` and swapped the `x` & `y` with `rx` & `ry` was trying to draw & center the entire image in the bitmap resized for rotation. This is what I have now: https://pastebin.com/rzvFpaD9 

Any ideas on how I can render the write pixels to their new size & location?